# Clojure data structure translation

Tags: list, optimization, clojure, tree

I need to translate an array map that has this structure:

```
{A [(A B) (A C)], C [(C D)], B [(B nil)], D [(D E) (D F)]}
```

Into this equivalent list:

```
'(A (B (nil)) (C (D (E) (F))))
```

I have this function that works just fine for not that deep structures:

```
(def to-tree (memoize (fn [start nodes]
     (list* start
          (if-let [connections (seq (nodes start))]
            (map #(to-tree (second %) nodes) connections))))))
```

However, as the n of nested elements grows, it gives off stack overflow error. How can I optimize this function, or rather, is there a way of doing this using walk or any other functional approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input data that you provide looks a lot like an adjacency list. One approach you could take would be to convert your data into a graph and then create trees from it.

Here is a solution using [loom](https://github.com/aysylu/loom) to work with graphs. This example only uses one function from loom ([`loom.graph/digraph`](http://aysy.lu/loom/loom.graph.html#var-digraph)), so you could probably build something similar if adding a dependency is not an option for you.

Let's start by creating a directed graph from your data structure.

```
(defn adj-list
  "Converts the data structure into an adjacency list."
  [ds]
  (into {} (map
            ;; convert [:a [[:a :b] [:a :c]]] => [:a [:b :c]]
            (fn [[k vs]] [k (map second vs)])
            ds)))

(defn ds->digraph
  "Creates a directed graph that mirrors the data structure."
  [ds]
  (loom.graph/digraph (adj-list ds)))
```

Once we have the graph built, we want to generate the trees from the root nodes of the graph. In your example, there is only one root node (`A`), but there is really nothing limiting it to just one.

Loom stores a list of all nodes in the graph as well as a set of all nodes with incoming edges to a given node in the graph. We can use these to find the root nodes.

```
(defn roots
  "Finds the set of nodes that are root nodes in the graph.

   Root nodes are those with no incoming edges."
  [g]
  (clojure.set/difference (:nodeset g)
                          (set (keys (:in g)))))
```

Given the root nodes, we now just need to create a tree for each. We can query the graph for the nodes adjacent to a given node, and then create trees for those recursively.

```
(defn to-tree [g n]
  "Given a node in a graph, create a tree (lazily).

   Assumes that n is a node in g."
  (if-let [succ (get-in g [:adj n])]
    (cons n (lazy-seq (map #(to-tree g %) succ)))
    (list n)))

(defn to-trees
  "Convert a graph into a collection of trees, one for each root node."
  [g]
  (map #(to-tree g %) (roots g)))
```

...and that's it! Taking your input, we can generate the desired output:

```
(def input {:a [[:a :b] [:a :c]] :c [[:c :d]] :b [[:b nil]] :d [[:d :e] [:d :f]]})
(first (to-trees (ds->digraph input))) ; => (:a (:c (:d (:e) (:f))) (:b (nil)))
```

Here are a couple of inputs for generating structures that are deep or have multiple root nodes.

```
(def input-deep (into {} (map (fn [[x y z]] [x [[x y] [x z]]]) (partition 3 2 (range 1000)))))
(def input-2-roots {:a [[:a :b] [:a :c]] :b [[:b nil]] :c [[:c :d]] :e [[:e :b] [:e :d]]})

(to-trees (ds->digraph input-2-roots)) ; => ((:e (:b (nil)) (:d)) (:a (:c (:d)) (:b (nil))))
```

One of the cool things about this approach is that it can work with *infinitely* nested data structures since generating the tree is lazy. You will get a StackOverflowException if you try to render the tree (because it also infinitely nested), but actually generating it is no problem.

The easiest way to play with this is to create a structure with a cycle, such as in the following example. (Note that the `:c` node is necessary. If only `:a` and `:b` are in the graph, there are no root nodes!)

```
(def input-cycle {:a [[:a :b]] :b [[:b :a]] :c [[:c :a]]})

(def ts (to-trees (ds->digraph input-cycle)))
(-> ts first second first)        ;; :a
(-> ts first second second first) ;; :b
```

You can test for this condition using [`loom.alg/dag?`](http://aysy.lu/loom/loom.alg.html#var-dag.3F).